# Bash, script that check soft

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-scripting, path

i have a script on bash:

```
s=0
 if [ -f /usr/bin/curl ] && [ -x /usr/bin/curl ] ; then
    echo  "Utility ...... curl [ ok ]"
    else
    echo  "Utility ...... curl [fail]"
    s=1
 fi
 if [ -f "/bin/grep" ] && [ -x "/bin/grep" ] ; then
    echo  "Utility ...... grep [ ok ]"
    else
    echo  "Utility ...... grep [fail]"
    s=1
 fi
 if [ -f "/usr/bin/expr" ] && [ -x "/usr/bin/expr" ] ; then
    echo  "Utility ...... expr [ ok ]"
    else
    echo  "Utility ...... expr [fail]"
    s=1
 fi
 if [ -f "/bin/sed" ] && [ -x "/bin/sed" ] ; then
    echo  "Utility ...... sed  [ ok ]"
    else
    echo  "Utility ...... sed  [fail]"
    s=1
 fi
 if [ $s -eq 0 ]; then
    echo  "All seems to be good. Let's play."
 else
    echo  "Please install requirement util! "
 fi
```

I want write without /usr/bin or /bin. I want write one variable:

```
$ENV/curl
```

And others ... 
How to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ -x "$(which curl)" ] ; then
    echo  "Utility ...... curl [ ok ]"
    else
    echo  "Utility ...... curl [fail]"
    s=1
fi
```

Comment: it is ok. but, i need to use one variable to all environments

Comment: You should use  only   if [ -x "$(which curl)" ].  If a command exists then , which will return the full path and -x will check for executable.

Comment: "which" command will search for the file in all the paths defined in $PATH variable. If you want to search other directories you can add the path in the $PATH variable.

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you do not want to write /usr/bin , /bin you can use "which"